# An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Core.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Hello when ever I click a button I need to get some voice in Hindi language which is in a text block.The following the code but when I click button in emulator I m getting the following exception.I'm unable to understand it pls help me to get out of this...

```
private async void btnSpeak_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{                     
    string filterLanguage = "";
    SpeechSynthesizer speech = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    filterLanguage = "hi-IN";

    IEnumerable<VoiceInformation> voices = from voice in InstalledVoices.All
                                           where voice.Language == filterLanguage
                                           select voice;

    speech.SetVoice(voices.ElementAt(0));
    await speech.SpeakTextAsync(lblTranslatedText.Text);   
}
```

and the exceptions I'm getting are:-

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233086
Message=Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index
Source=System.Core
ParamName=index
StackTrace:
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ElementAt[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Int32 index)
   at Learn_Hindi.MainPage.<btnSpeak_Click>d__6.MoveNext()
InnerException:
```

Comment: hm. Based on exception info there are no elements at the *voices* collection.

Comment: @Ivan Zub could you explain me clearly?

Comment: You query is returning no records, so `voices.ElementAt(0)` is not valid because `voices` is empty.

Comment: @kotlasaicharanreddy sure. So you're quering *InstalledVoices.All* trying to filter it by *filterLanguage*. But when you're trying to actually enumerate this query (to get items from it) using *voices.ElementAt(0)* you're getting *ArgumentOutOfRangeException* exception. That exception means that there is no element by the '0' index at *voices* collection.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your Linq statement returns an empty collection sometimes. Try to check if there is any elements in the voices object before trying to get specific elements:

```
if (voices.Any())
{
    speech.SetVoice(voices.ElementAt(0));
    await speech.SpeakTextAsync(lblTranslatedText.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do proper testing on your collection. Your exception occurs because you are trying to access a voice element that does not exist. The requested voice your're filtering for is not installed on your emulator.

```
IEnumerable<VoiceInformation> voices = from voice in InstalledVoices.All
                                       where voice.Language == filterLanguage
                                       select voice;
try {
    speech.SetVoice(voices.ElementAt(0));
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Show a message box or whatever to explain that the voice is not installed.
}
```